# Can i change the text "view project" on button with javascript or jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to change the text "view project" of button at this page:
https://new.emanuelemarazzi.com/pacchetti-creativi/

If you see the code there is a span under a class.

I tried to use jQuery with this code:

```
$('.button-style5 span').text('Text changed');
```

Answer (score 1):

This is working  :

```js
$('.button-style5 span').text('Text changed1');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
.button-style5 {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: inherit;
    font-size: 12px;
    background: 0 0;
    padding: 7px 15px;
    line-height: 19px;
    border: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: middle;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: lowercase;
    font-weight: 300;
    border: 1px solid;
    border-radius: 15px;
    opacity: .8;
}
</style>

<div style="color:blue;" class="button-style5"><span >abc view project</span><i class="material-design-icon-keyboard-right-arrow-button"></i></div>
```

Comment: It works. 
thank you very much.

i missed the script of jquery.

thanks my friend

Answer (score 0):

No need for JQ.

```js
document
    .querySelectorAll('.button-style5 span')
    .forEach(span=> span.innerText = 'All your span are belong to us')
```

References:

[Document​.query​SelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)
[HTMLElement​.inner​Text](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/innerText)

Answer (score 0):

[image: REFER SAME IMG]
Seems like your Solution is working

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(".owl-item .button-style5 span").each(function() {
  this.textContent = "Text Changed";
});
```